# Opencart 2.3.0.2 : Category image on product pages

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I kinda know this should be a fairly simple thing to do, but in my opencart 2.3.0.2 webshop, I want to display the category image on product pages.

But i cant find how to retrieve the image....  At this moment i have this piece of code :

```
  <div class="catthumb">
    <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
  <div class="category-bg" style="    
     background: url('<?php echo $thumb; ?>') no-repeat center center; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.<?php echo $thumb; ?>', sizingMethod='scale');
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='<?php echo $thumb; ?>', sizingMethod='scale')";">
  </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

The following code doesn't do the trick.. Ofcourse i've changed the variable along with the code.

```
        if ($category_info) {
            if ($category_info['image']) {
            $this->data['thumbcat'] = "../image/".($category_info['image']);
            } else {
            $this->data['thumbcat'] = '';
            }
        }
```

But this displays the poduct thumb, instead of the category thumb, the product belongs to.

So the question is how to get the category image there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this $thumb seems to be referring to the product thumb, so you'll have to get in the product controller and fetch the category picture and save it in new variable then work with the new variable.

Comment: I've edited my post, the code is what isn't working... I use the variable thumbcat along with it instead op just thumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the category image code with below code in product controller:

```
if ($category_info) {
   if ($category_info['image']) {
      $data['thumbcat'] = "../image/".($category_info['image']);
   } else {
      $data['thumbcat'] = '';
   }
}
```

then use **$thumbcat** instead of **$thumb** to display category image in you product.tpl file.